# Use of Unresolved identifier 'RealmOptional'

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I am creating a simple model class for realm in swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class SampleModel: RLMObject {
    dynamic var datauuid: String = ""
    let age = RealmOptional<Int>() //Line 6(getting the error here)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "datauuid"
    }
}
```

But i am getting the error **Use of unresolved identifier 'RealOptional'** in line 6. Can anyone help me to resolve the error
I am using Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b), and swift: Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42)

Comment: If you are using Swift, you should import RealmSwift and also model your classes with *Object* (which is swift) instead of RLMObject (Obj-c).

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using the objective-c version of Realm and the issue occurs when trying to set an optional value in a swift model. "import RealmSwift" is not available for the obj-c version.

Comment: @PantelisProios I created a new Obj-C Realm project and added a couple of classes that contained optional properties to it . It built and ran correctly, and I was able to create the classes and read/write from Realm. Since this is a Swift based question that may have an unrelated issue (and solution per the import Realmswift solution) can you create a new question with example code and a description of the problem?

Comment: @Jay, i do not see the reason creating a new question since i am having the exact same issue trying to (properly) create optionals in swift. You may have created optionals without using "RealmOptional" but this is against their documentation https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/RealmOptional.html . Importing "RealmSwift" is not an option/solution if you have a mixed (swift & objc) project.

Comment: @PantelisProios That's up to you. You're first comment states *I am using the objective-c version of Realm* and then your second comment states you are *trying to (properly) create optionals in swift*. If this is a swift project, you need to include *import RealmSwift* and (to be complete) define your Swift Realm Objects as type *Object* instead of the Obj-C *RLMObject*. This is why I suggested a new question since the situation appears to be different and more complex. The OP tagged this as Swift, not Obj-C. Just trying to help..

Comment: Oh - and RLMObjects (Obj-c) don't have a RealmOptional option, from the Realm Obj-C docs *Storing optional numbers is done using NSNumber * properties* and they *must be tagged with one of RLMInt, RLMFloat, RLMDouble, or RLMBool*

Answer (score 0):

Import Realm library:

```
import RealmSwift
```

If error will not disappear, check linked libraries

Eg if your project use CocoaPods packages, add following string to `Podfile`:

```
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

and launch

```
pod install
```

in project library

Look https://cocoapods.org/ for details (or appropriate documentation for your package manager if you are use some other)